# identifying unused paths (by the xslt) in an xml document (or schema)

Tags: xslt

If i have an xsd schema, is it possible to identify what parts of the schema arent actually referenced by an XSLT file?

(I have done similar things in schema captured in statically typed languages, but the languages are more constrained than xslt).

Comment: I think with Saxon EE and schema-aware XSLT 2/3 Saxon is able to warn you the other way around, if you have e.g. match patterns and/or paths that don't match anything in the schema. As for not matched parts in the input, I think `<xsl:mode warning-on-no-match="yes"/>` will do that.

Comment: yep...exactly....its basically inferring a a type based on usage and then saying the type isnt consistent with the schema type...in statically typed languages this sort of thing is much easier...not perfect...but it can tell you whats NOT referenced too.

Comment: I suppose i can start with an empty schema and add stuff based on saxon's complaints until it stops moaning. Obviously things like the identty transform will never moan, I'd have to handle them empiracally

Comment: Other than the previous comments, in the context of processing XSD schemas with XSLT and Saxon one hint that usually comes up is to create an SCM https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/schema-processing/scm.html first as "applications that need access to schema information can find it much more readily in an SCM document than in the source schema".

Comment: ah ok...I'll look it up

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to do by static analysis, because many stylesheets include fallback behaviour such as `match="*"` templates. Also it depends what you mean by "referenced". If a stylesheet copies subtrees in bulk using `xsl:copy-of select="section"`, or deletes subtrees in bulk using `<xsl:template match="section"/>`, do you consider elements within those subtrees to be "referenced" or not?

I would suggest (a) trying to make sure that your test data has good coverage of the schema, and (b) using `on-no-match="fail"` on an xsl:mode declaration to make sure that all elements are processed using explicit template rules rather than fallback rules.

Saxon offers some instrumentation -- the `-stats` option on the `Validate` command line - that can help in discovering how much of your schema is covered by your test data.

*Update after initial comments*

I recall another technique I once used to check coverage of the schema: I analysed a schema (using Saxon's SCM extract, but any schema API would do) to produce a list of allowed parent-child element pairs, and then I processed the test data to produce another list of parent-child element pairs, and compared the two. Of course that's incomplete, for example it doesn't look at whether  all repeatable elements are actually repeated and whether all optional elements are actually omitted, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: yes...so in a statically typed version of this...a bit more like XQuery, anything referenced at all, even if it doesnt appear in the output or have any impact is considered used. Its a bit like the inherent type inference problem of referencing something in code that can never be run..

Comment: the match fail is interesting...I was going to run the transform against example data, and then remove things from the schema, and remove the corresponding data from the example data. If the output remains unchanged, then I can assume (if the test data covers every eventuality) that the removed schema references are unused....its a 'test' driven approach though...your "fail" suggestion may be a bit more efficient